# Навигация пв телеграм боте

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Для примера как реализована навигация в botfather

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попробовал реализовать аналог удаляя предыдущее сообщение, вот что получилось
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

явно не так, видимо в botfather это сделано иначе, собственно вопрос, как?

Answer (score 0):

разобрался, нужно менять сообщение через EditMessageText